# Intersect two sf data.frames based on date and geometry using R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, spatial, r-sf

So, I have two R "sf" "data.frames", one with millions of linestring geometries (vsr_segments: see below) and the other with 5 polygons (vsr_zones: see below). Each linestring has a datetime and each polygon has a unique date range.

I'm trying to intersect the linestrings dataframe with the polygon data.frame based on whether the linestring datetime falls within a specific polygon's date range. 
Basically, if this linestring datetime is within any of the polygons' date ranges, perform the intersect with the appropriate polygon, and return a sf data.frame of the linestrings that intersect.

I have a sql query that essentially does this but this only works on my postgres database.

source: https://postgis.net/2014/03/14/tip_intersection_faster/

I'm curious if there' a better way to do this. It's simple, but when new data comes in, I have to drop the table, create a new one, and create new indexes.

I'd rather have a way where I only run this datetime within date range spatial intersection with new data (sf data.frame with ~5000 linestrings) and append the resulting data.frame to the existing database table.
Is there an r way to do this? I've tried sqldf to perform the query below with my r data.frames versus performing the query on my database. Any assistance would be very appreciated.

```
query = ("CREATE TABLE vsr_segments AS
            SELECT
            s.name, s.mmsi, s.speed,
            s.seg_mins, s.seg_km,
            s.seg_kmhr, s.seg_knots, s.speed_diff,
            s.year, s.beg_dt, s.end_dt,
            s.beg_lon, s.beg_lat,
            s.end_lon, s.end_lat, z.gid,
            CASE
            WHEN
            ST_CoveredBy(s.geometry, z.geom)
            THEN s.geometry
            ELSE
            ST_Multi(
            ST_Intersection(s.geometry, z.geom)
            ) END AS geometry
            FROM ais_segments AS s
            INNER JOIN vsr_zones AS z
            ON ST_Intersects(s.geometry, z.geom)
            WHERE
            s.datetime::date <= z.date_end AND
            s.datetime >= z.date_beg;")

    dbExecute(con, query)
```

sample data

```
vsr_segments <- structure(list(
datetime = structure(c(1573348510.52, 1573348830.935, 
1573349296.305, 1573349746.216, 1573349840.846, 1573350013.303, 
1573350371.104, 1573350793.237, 1573350929.837, 1573351206.262, 
1573351530.493, 1573351598.156, 1573351686.598, 1573353232.418, 
1573353368.013, 1573353476.023, 1573354582.045, 1573355374.706, 
1573355522.445, 1573355611.793), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), 
name = c("ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", 
"ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", 
"ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", "ALAN T", 
"ALAN T", "ALAN T"), 
geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-119.498252, 
-119.49837, 34.375007, 34.37505), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.49837, -119.498255, 34.37505, 
34.374992), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"
)), structure(c(-119.498255, -119.498193, 34.374992, 34.374958
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498193, 
-119.498303, 34.374958, 34.375055), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498303, -119.498337, 
34.375055, 34.375078), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-119.498337, -119.49841, 34.375078, 34.375062
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.49841, 
-119.498435, 34.375062, 34.375055), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498435, -119.498368, 
34.375055, 34.375092), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-119.498368, -119.498357, 34.375092, 34.375058
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498357, 
-119.498292, 34.375058, 34.375048), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498325, -119.498342, 
34.375035, 34.375053), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-119.498342, -119.498427, 34.375053, 34.375072
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498427, 
-119.49849, 34.375072, 34.375062), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498505, -119.498617, 
34.375062, 34.375048), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-119.498617, -119.498602, 34.375037, 34.375027
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498602, 
-119.498607, 34.375027, 34.375028), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498607, -119.498267, 
34.375028, 34.374993), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-119.498267, -119.4989, 34.374993, 34.374715
), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.4989, 
-119.498898, 34.374715, 34.374748), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-119.498898, -119.4989, 34.374748, 
34.374723), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"
))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -119.4989, 
ymin = 34.374715, xmax = -119.498193, ymax = 34.375092), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = c("sf", "data.table", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(datetime = NA_integer_, 
name = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"))


vsr_zones <- structure(list(
gid = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
vsr_category = c("2019", 
"2017v1", "2017v2", "2017v3", "2018"), 
date_beg = structure(c(18031, 
17318, 17348, 17508, 17686), class = "Date"), 
date_end = structure(c(18215, 
17347, 17507, 17590, 17896), class = "Date"), 
date_range = structure(c("(\"2019-05-15 00:00:00+00\",\"2019-11-15 23:59:59.99+00\")", 
"(\"2017-07-01 00:00:00+00\",\"2017-12-07 23:59:59.99+00\")", 
"(\"2017-07-01 00:00:00+00\",\"2017-12-07 23:59:59.99+00\")", 
"(\"2017-12-08 00:00:00+00\",\"2018-02-28 23:59:59.99+00\")", 
"(\"2018-06-04 00:00:00+00\",\"2018-12-31 23:59:59.99+00\")"), class = "pq_tstzrange"), 
    rec_speed_knots = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
geom = structure(list(
        structure(list(list(structure(c(-120.632908463866, -120.604354931796, 
        -120.58151210614, -120.55676571168, -120.530115748414, 
        -120.509176491563, -120.492044372321, -120.476815821884, 
        -120.465394409056, -120.429226601767, -120.383540950455, 
        -120.343566005557, -120.294073216636, -120.252194702933, 
        -120.223641170863, -120.179859088356, -120.126559161826, 
        -120.084680648123, -120.058030684857, -120.037091428006, 
        -120.021862877569, -120.006634327132, -119.95714153821, 
        -119.922877299726, -119.877191648414, -119.844830978735, 
        -119.825795290689, -119.791531052205, -119.709677593604, 
        -119.686834767948, -119.639245547831, -119.58975275891, 
        -119.56119922684, -119.53645283238, -119.483152905849, 
        -119.458406511388, -119.439370823342, -119.38987803442, 
        -119.372745915178, -119.30802457582, -119.290892456578, 
        -119.266146062117, -119.22236397961, -119.207135429173, 
        -119.121474832963, -119.091017732088, -119.037717805557, 
        -119.005357135878, -118.933021521301, -118.847360925091, 
        -118.799771704974, -118.784543154537, -118.735050365616, 
        -118.681750439085, -118.664618319843, -118.613221962117, 
        -118.544693485149, -118.491393558619, -118.451418613721, 
        -118.390504411972, -118.388600843167, -118.400022255995, 
        -118.424768650456, -118.405732962409, -118.36956515512, 
        -118.280097421301, -118.247736751622, -118.186822549873, 
        -118.186822549873, -118.165883293021, -118.110679797686, 
        -118.064994146374, -118.019308495062, -117.964104999727, 
        -117.906997935587, -117.85940871547, -117.808012357744, 
        -117.781362394479, -117.710930348707, -117.680473247832, 
        -117.638594734129, -117.587198376403, -117.571969825966, 
        -117.505344917803, -117.480260689924, -121.029936561572, 
        -121.029936561572, -120.646233445499, -120.632908463866, 
        34.5567050238998, 34.5528978862905, 34.5548014550951, 
        34.5395729046579, 34.5319586294392, 34.5205372166113, 
        34.4900801157366, 34.4786587029085, 34.44249089562, 34.448201602034, 
        34.4596230148619, 34.4577194460573, 34.4691408588853, 
        34.4615265836666, 34.4748515652994, 34.4672372900806, 
        34.4710444276899, 34.4577194460573, 34.4596230148619, 
        34.4596230148619, 34.4577194460573, 34.4596230148619, 
        34.4329730515967, 34.431069482792, 34.4082266571361, 
        34.4006123819174, 34.4120337947453, 34.4158409323548, 
        34.391094537894, 34.4082266571361, 34.41393736355, 34.4158409323548, 
        34.4101302259407, 34.3968052443081, 34.3777695562615, 
        34.3720588498474, 34.35683029941, 34.3168553545121, 34.3187589233168, 
        34.273073272005, 34.273073272005, 34.244519739935, 34.1436305932877, 
        34.1455341620923, 34.0979449419757, 34.0960413731712, 
        34.078909253929, 34.0655842722966, 34.0408378778358, 
        34.0313200338124, 33.9951522265239, 34.01799505218, 34.0313200338124, 
        34.0294164650079, 34.0370307402266, 34.0332236026171, 
        34.0370307402266, 34.0046700705472, 33.9589844192354, 
        33.8352524469322, 33.8143131900808, 33.8047953460574, 
        33.7781453827922, 33.7343633002849, 33.7362668690895, 
        33.7039061994104, 33.7457847131129, 33.7381704378942, 
        33.7591096947457, 33.7610132635502, 33.7438811443082, 
        33.711520474629, 33.6677383921216, 33.6258598784191, 
        33.6011134839584, 33.5839813647164, 33.5478135574277, 
        33.5382957134045, 33.4583458236086, 33.4583458236086, 
        33.4355029979527, 33.3783959338127, 33.3783959338127, 
        33.3365174201101, 33.299879212642, 33.299879212642, 34.5736940817683, 
        34.5738371431418, 34.5567050238998), .Dim = c(89L, 2L
        )))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
            list(structure(c(-120.873273035994, -120.873274461718, 
            -120.487219702881, -120.506822270857, -120.873273035994, 
            34.3781494612153, 34.4709485281576, 34.3814708197392, 
            34.2930682831847, 34.3781494612153), .Dim = c(5L, 
            2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), 
        structure(list(list(structure(c(-120.876185794554, -120.873274695607, 
        -119.449753967941, -119.469363746559, -120.876185794554, 
        34.3960669578761, 34.4861721639365, 34.1563446852463, 
        34.0713786726887, 34.3960669578761), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
        "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(-120.050247166472, 
        -120.027227238885, -119.26260029791, -119.285620225496, 
        -120.050247166472, 34.1816435818833, 34.2854817798431, 
        34.1159713573041, 34.0121331593446, 34.1816435818833), .Dim = c(5L, 
        2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
            list(structure(c(-118.986389683899, -118.994289494438, 
            -119.276683926611, -119.874404531275, -120.177071971217, 
            -120.709119452121, -120.873778153724, -120.873274108521, 
            -120.672951644832, -120.507341158826, -120.343634241625, 
            -120.195155874861, -119.90105449454, -119.744010068156, 
            -119.586013857368, -119.427065862179, -119.249082178943, 
            -118.974016486669, -118.986389683899, 33.9223965975751, 
            33.9007910916422, 34.0337553726479, 34.1698605421817, 
            34.2383890191496, 34.3592656382457, 34.397337014339, 
            34.4479592752089, 34.403047720753, 34.3649763446597, 
            34.3278567529687, 34.2935925144848, 34.2279193907238, 
            34.1917515834352, 34.1555837761465, 34.1203677532603, 
            34.0794410239599, 33.9471429920358, 33.9223965975751
            ), .Dim = c(19L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
        "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -121.029936561572, 
    ymin = 33.299879212642, xmax = -117.480260689924, ymax = 34.5738371431418
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geom", agr = structure(c(gid = NA_integer_, 
vsr_category = NA_integer_, date_beg = NA_integer_, date_end = NA_integer_, 
date_range = NA_integer_, rec_speed_knots = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

Comment: `Pardon the poor sample data` - If you want specific help you're going to have to supply good quality example data which other people can copy & paste into their R session and use directly. Otherwise you're asking people to create an example data set for you, which most people are unwilling to do

Comment: `but when new data comes in, I have to drop the table, create a new one, and create new indexes.` - you could insert the new data into a temp table, do the query, then append the results into your main table?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Sorry about that. I added easy copy/paste dput sample data so if anyone wants to take a swing at this problem, it'll be pretty doable. I only kept datetime, name, and geometry for the vsr_segments df, so that SQL won't have as many select attributes, if there's a cool sqldf solution.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Good call! I just did the temporary table/append method, but I'm really curious to see a R solution to this. Especially since this step is like #5 out of 20, so I'd like a way to perform my date range spatial intersect in R then continue analysis in R without having to query the database and pull that intersect data back into R.. if that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two-step approach could be to do a range join (or non-equi join) to find which rows of data overlap by date range, then a pair-wise geometry intersection to tell you whether they intersect spatially or not

I like using `library(data.table)` for all joining operations because of its superior memory management and speed

```r
library(sf)
library(data.table)

setDT( vsr_segments )
setDT( vsr_zones )

## add a row_index onto segments
## (I'm assuming gid is a unique id on vsr_zones)
vsr_segments[, row_id := .I ]

## make a POSIXct column so we can do a range join (on the same data)
vsr_zones[
  , `:=`(
    posix_beg = as.POSIXct( date_beg )   ## set whichever timezone is appropriate
    , posix_end = as.POSIXct( date_end )
  )
]

## use a range join (or non-equi join) to give you the overlapping geometries in time
dt <- vsr_zones[
  vsr_segments
  , on = .(posix_beg <= datetime, posix_end >= datetime)
] 

dt[, int := list( sf::st_intersection( geom, geometry )), by = .(row_id)]

## now the 'int' column is the geometry created by the intersection of geom and geometry
```

Comment: @ SymbolixAU Thank You! I ran your solution and it seems to work. I need to double check with other sample data to see if it is truly working correctly... I think your original idea of just write new data to a temp_table -> perform sql intersect on temp -> append to main table is superior. Even with data.tables speed, it still took a really long time to handle a larger sf data.frame (100,000 linestrings). Whereas the sql intersect I wrote in my question takes 270 seconds to run through 17 million linestring intersects based on being within a certain polygons date range.

Comment: yeah sounds like the temp table is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

#rename
ais_segments_temp <- vsr_segments
#my db connection...
con

update_vsr_segments <- function(con = NULL){

# SQL Date and Geometry intersect query
  # Creates "vsr_segments_temp" table which will be inserted into "vsr_segments" table.
  query = ("CREATE TABLE vsr_segments_temp AS
            SELECT
            s.name, s.mmsi, s.speed,
            s.seg_mins, s.seg_km,
            s.seg_kmhr, s.seg_knots, s.speed_diff,
            s.beg_dt, s.end_dt,
            s.beg_lon, s.beg_lat,
            s.end_lon, s.end_lat, z.gid,
            CASE
            WHEN
            ST_CoveredBy(s.geometry, z.geom)
            THEN s.geometry
            ELSE
            ST_Multi(
            ST_Intersection(s.geometry, z.geom)
            ) END AS geometry
            FROM ais_segments_temp AS s
            INNER JOIN vsr_zones AS z
            ON ST_Intersects(s.geometry, z.geom)
            WHERE
            s.datetime::date <= z.date_end AND
            s.datetime >= z.date_beg;")

  # get list of tables in database
  database_tables_list = db_list_tables(con)
  # made a 'not within' function
  if ('vsr_segments_temp' %!in% database_tables_list){

    dbExecute(con, query)

  }

  else if ('vsr_segments_temp' %in% database_tables_list){

    dbRemoveTable(con, "vsr_segments_temp")

    dbExecute(con, query)
  }

else {

  print(NULL)

  }
}

update_vsr_segments(con = con)

dbExecute(con, "INSERT INTO vsr_segments
SELECT * FROM vsr_segments_temp;")

dbDisconnect(con)
```